# Null is not an object, making dropdown

Tags: javascript

I want my code to give every element with class `ddown` an event that will ad a `slactive` class to the actual dropdown. However the console says that `document.getElementById('sl'+(n+1))` is null so not an object. But, if I not use `n` inside the function in event, this works fine, but only for the first element. Elements are named like sl1,sl2,sl3,...

```
ddown = document.getElementsByClassName('ddown');
for(var n=0; n<ddown.length; n++) {
    ddown[n].addEventListener('mousedown', function(){document.getElementById('sl'+(n+1)).classList.add('slactive');});
    console.log('sl'+(n+1));
}
```

P.S. `console.log` gives the right codes, I think the problem is in the scope of `n`.

Comment: Something you might notice, typeof(null) is actually "object".

Comment: @vothaison I've written the console output in different words.

Comment: Well, gurvinder372 is correct. You case is called "accident closure" ^^ .

Answer (score 2):

You need to lock down the value of n before adding the listener.

Replace your line (which is adding the listener) by

```
(function (n){ ddown[n].addEventListener('mousedown', function(){document.getElementById('sl'+(n+1)).classList.add('slactive');}); )(n)
```